# Python, Truth value ambiguous error, Optimization

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

When using optimization (e.g. `brentq`), the input is always an array of items. However, sometimes it is necessary to use a comparator function like `>=` in object function. Then, python is not able to evaluate those values.

For example:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x
    if x <= 0:
        return -x

optimize.brentq(f,-1,1)
```

Then we will have the error: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous`.

In general, how to avoid this error?

Comment: Start by reading the rest of the error message. It has some suggestions of what to do.

Comment: Search SO with the error message and start reading the Q&A's to get a feel for the issue.

Comment: Do you want the condition to be True if ALL the elements of `x` meet the condition or just ANY of them.? What is supposed to happen for `if [True,False,True]:`?

Comment: [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 0):

If `f` is what you actually need, use `np.abs` instead. If it's a dummy example, use something like this instead:

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(x>0, x, -x)
```

In general change

```
def f(x):
    if condition(x):
        return f1(x)
    else:
        return f2(x)
```

to

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(condition(x), f1(x), f2(x))
```

keeping in mind that for non trivial conditions, your implementation should still be able to handle vectors... (i.e. if `x` is a vector `condition(x)` should return a vector of the same size as `x`)